# PHP mail html format not working

Tags: php, email

Using php, and with this code I receive the email as a plain text, did I miss something? as I need to send formatted email which could contain links for example.

```
$to = "receiver@test.com";
$subject = "Password Recovery";

$body = '
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: info@test.net\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
echo "Password recovery instructions been sent to your email<br>";
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at this example, this is sufficient to send mail in php:

```
<?php 
    //change this to your email. 
    $to = "abc@gmail.com";
    $from = "Example@example.com";
    $subject = "Hello! This is HTML email";

    //begin of HTML message 
    $message ="
<html> 
  <body> 
    <p style=\"text-align:center;height:100px;background-color:#abc;border:1px solid #456;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;\">
        <b>I am receiving HTML email</b>
        <br/><br/><br/><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#246;\" href=\"www.example.com\">example</a>
    </p>
    <br/><br/>Now you Can send HTML Email
  </body>
</html>";
   //end of message 
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    //options to send to cc+bcc 
    //$headers .= "Cc: [email]maa@p-i-s.cXom[/email]"; 
    //$headers .= "Bcc: [email]email@maaking.cXom[/email]"; 

    // now lets send the email. 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

    echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 23):

You've re-set your headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: info@test.net\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```

You're missing a dot in that last line, which is over-writing the previous two:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@test.net\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```

Comment: @andrewsi thanks I was also having similar problem with missing .

Comment: Buddy you saved the day :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem with a specific mail server, in my case the solution was to set "\n" instead of "\r\n" as the end of line for the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your problem seems to be caused by re-assigning to $headers, I've ran into a similar problem and discovered the cause to be the double line-ending "/r/n". Some mail apps such as Bluemail, start the mail body (effectively ending the headers) after reading a double line ending.

In my case, it was solved by changing this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@test.net\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```

to this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers = "From: info@test.net\n"."X-Mailer: php";
```