# Emailing HTML through PHP File

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I am having trouble trying to display my html code properly (without the html tags) when it gets sent out through email via a php file. What `$header` or `$nmessage` am I missing for it to display properly when a recipient receives the email?

My php script is shown below with the html code left out:

```
<?php

if(@$_REQUEST['weakPassword'] != "TEST")
{
echo "failed";
die();
}

function mail_attachment_from_file($the_file, $filename , $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) 
{
$content = $the_file;
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= "--".$uid."--";

mail($mailto, $subject, $nmessage, $header);

return true;
}

$to = @$_REQUEST['emailGuest'];
$from = @$_REQUEST['emailFrom'];

$subject = @$_REQUEST['emailSubject'];

$message = '
<html>
// HTML code
</html>';

$fileName = @$_REQUEST['fileName'];

$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

// Read in our file attachment
$the_file = file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);

mail_attachment_from_file($the_file, $fileName , $to, $from, "BLAH", $from, $subject, $message);

echo "done";

?>
```

Comment: `Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` this is your culprit. You are saying that the email is sent with plain text format

Comment: You may also want to consider using PEAR or other libraries that can assist in creating the proper MIME Boundaries for your mail. This will help ensure it looks less like SPAM and meets RFC Standards. Also remember that RFC states if you are sending HTML Formatted email, there should be a proper TEXT MIME version too.

Comment: @Twisty would you recommend PEAR or the [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library?

Comment: I am a fan of PEAR personally. https://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=14&catname=Mail Try Mail2 and Mail_MIME2.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Content-Type` to this:

```
$nmessage .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
```

From this:

```
$nmessage .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994556/php-mail-html-format-not-working):